# Using Yeoman to build ng2 component

Tags: angular, yeoman

I got it in my head to try and write a tool to speed up Angular 2 development, by bootstrapping in a new component complete with template, .ts file, and .spec.ts file.

So if I am inside a given directory /components:

```
/components
|--/component1
|--/component2
 ...
```

I want to make a custom Yeoman generator to take a prompt value "`newComponent`" and build out

```
/components
|--/component1
|--/component2
|--/newComponent
   |--newComponent.html
   |--newComponent.ts
   |--newComponent.spec.ts
 ...
```

from a template folder, replacing `${myNewComponent}` with `newComponent` in each file (or other similar templating engine).

Yeoman seems like the best tool for this, but most tutorials I've found talk about using Yeoman to scaffold out an entire project/site, which is far bigger than what I'm trying to build.

Comment: Have you considered using angular-cli? It does exactly this (among other things). Have a look at `ng generate`: https://cli.angular.io/reference.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!